# Windows Server 2016 - Setting up a file share. Permissions work with individual users, but not groups?

Tags: network-share, windows-server-2016, file-permissions

So here is my issue.  It's been a while since I last set up a file server (2007), and am currently working on the beginnings of one for my current company.

The issue I am running into is this:

I have a loose folder structure in place and am beginning to assign permissions.  What I am finding is that when I give myself permissions to a root folder structure, I have access.  However, I also, under the account I am using, belong to the Domain Admins group.  When I remove myself, but leave in Domain Admins, it SHOULD work as the group I am a part of is listed as Full Control.

However, it doesn't - it locks me out until I add myself back individually.

Given that I want to manage these folders via security groups and not as individuals, can someone provide some direction as to what I should be looking for? I already verified I am a part of "Domain/Domain Admins" via "whoamI /all", and the overall arching share that I am managing with Server Manager does show Domain Admins listed...

Comment: Are you referring to local access or over the network?

Answer (score 3):

> However, I also, under the account I am using, belong to the Domain Admins group

Your answer is 'UAC'. The 'UAC' filters out the 'Administrator'/Domain Administrator' privileges from account for most processes.

I bet if you used a different group everything would work as you expect.

I suspect you are also attempting to test these permissions locally from the server.  If you were testing remotely you would also not have problems with the UAC, since the UAC filtering only applies locally.

Comment: IIRC, one workaround is to create a group like `my-administrators` and add the Domain Admins group to it.  You can then give permissions to `my-administrators` and they won't be filtered out.